# Umbraco: Admin password retrieval

Tags: visual-studio, passwords, umbraco, admin

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to install the umbraco through nuget. I have setup and running the demo site and logging into the backoffice screen. The next day I go and run the site again and try to log into the backoffice but i can't log into it. Assuming my password typed wrong. I went to  'forgot my password' page to reset my password but ican't receive any email from it.

I looked at the database but the password was hashed.

How do i get the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot password e-mail won't be sent if you haven't configured SMTP settings in your *web.config* file. But the problem is probably caused by different things e.g.:

1. DateTime change between system and database - it may cause problems with synchronization.
2. System files permissions (e.g. I'm struggling with Windows problem now which is resetting my user permissions from time to time... thanks Microsoft... and I'm unable to authorize my users in the backoffice from time to time).

If it's anything from above list, you need to perform additional checks and steps to solve the problem. But starting from resetting the password, the easiest way to solve your problem may be to use this simple, little package: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-admin-reset/ (DLL basically). When you'll place this DLL in the */bin* directory, during the app startup, it will reset your base user (with ID = 0) to login: **Admin** and password: **Admin1234!**.

Comment: @SerjSagan Report issue here: https://github.com/rsoeteman/umbraco-admin-reset if you want to still use it.

Comment: :) It actually might... my problem ended up being that the db user didn't have access to the custom (non-dbo) schema...

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are using the email address you entered during the install as the username, this has caught me out a few times before. Check in the database that the [userLogin] matches the username/email you are trying to login with. It's incredibly misleading (in my opinion) for newcomers to Umbraco that the [userName] column is really the users name and not the username.

If that doesn't help, check your browser console for errors - you may see a an error along the lines of `400 (Bad Request)` in which case I would refer you to this long thread on the forums which has lots of options to try and resolve the error:

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/50407-Login-failed-for-user-in-Umbraco-7

The one that has worked for me in the past is by adding the following in my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It's not advisable to leave this in your solution when it moves to production though as you will probably want tighter control over the allowed access control methods.

Comment: Thank advise. Probably not the solution for my problem coz I can log in after installed but tried to run on the next days i can't lock back in.

Comment: That is the issue I'm referring to.

Comment: Thanks, though your `customHeaders` didn't help, the link you gave got me on the right track. 2 things for me did it, 1) change the default schema of the db user in SQL to the custom one I had for Umbraco 2) look at the Chrome console error messages and Google those.